# Server to stream RTSP to android

Tags: android, flash-media-server, rtsp

Can Flash Media Server 3.5 serve a video rtsp stream to the Android media player?

Or do we need to use Wowza or red5 to serve an rtsp stream to the Android media player rtsp client?

Are there any other rtsp servers to consider when the video needs to be viewed on Android (without the Adobe Flash app)?

Comment: You are getting RTSP and RTMP confused. Flash only supports RTMP, and does not support RTSP. Android supports RTSP, and does not support RTMP. Because of this confusion, your question is contradicting itself.

Comment: No, I have not confused RTSP and RTMP, I think the question is quite clear - Can FMS3.5 serve RTSP?  The answer to date is no, but that might change in the future.  Furthermore, Android 2.2 with Flash does support RTMP - works fine on my Nexus one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FMS 3.5 does not support rtsp streaming.

Answer (score 5):

Try darwin streaming server. This can stream MPEG-4 and 3GPP.

Note that Videoplayer in Android supports RTSP streaming as per 3GPP PSS Streaming specifications. i.e fileformat is 3GP/MP4 and the supported codecs are MPEG-4 Video, AVC, MPEG4 Audio, AMR, and H263.

One potential drawback with darwin is you need 3rd party tools to do hinting first.There are several free hinting tools. Definitely worth a try.

[DarwinStreaming Server Link](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/server/streaming/index.html)

Comment: Do you know, does wowza requiring hinting?  Or is hinting something only Darwin Streaming server requires?

Comment: I am not sure about wowza. Any rtsp streaming would require hinting. Wowza might do it internally(Again,I am not sure).

Answer (score 2):

I could manage to play a RTSP stream in Android 2.3 with HTML5 on default browser, no external app, no flash plugin.

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" loop="loop">
<source src="rtsp://74.115.208.37:1935/live/luxweradio2_8403.stream" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

I explain each part:

-I'm using the default Android browser (also worked in Dolphin)

-The loop="loop" part made the stream actually play continuously, without that I heard like 0.1 seconds of audio each time I clicked play. Is this a hack or what?

-The autoplay="autoplay" part works, it actually auto-plays after some seconds (no feedback like "loading..." though)

-The type="audio/mpeg" for me it seems like Android browser ignores that, I've tried others like video/3GPP (yes, video) and still worked!

-I'm not sure if autobuffer="autobuffer" actually does anythinhg 'cause it isn't part of the HTML5 audio tag definition, but I've seen so many "bad" things that work... I should test some cases with and without, but it's pretty late now here in Argentina :P

Answer (score 0):

WOWZA 3 is able to serve the same stream in RTMP, HTTP and RTSP. I have it running it. It is publish as RTMP and delivered as RTMP, HTTP and RTSP at the same time.

See this: 
http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36#publish

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My Media Server / library supports streaming to Android or any other compatible RtspClient.

http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

Check out the article on CodeProject @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

If you need anything else let me know!