# Default Media Player in Android phones

Tags: android, rtsp

I understand that all Android phones will have the WebKit browser Application. 
Is there a default Media Player that can perform RTSP stream in all Android phones?
It seems OpenCore supoprts RTSP streaming - but is there a Media Player Application by default?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default videoplayer can stream RTSP, but your RTSP stream needs follow 3GPP PSS streaming spec.

There is some more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613737/server-to-stream-rtsp-to-android)