# How to link to an RTSP stream on Android phone?

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, rtsp

I need to play an RTSP audio stream on an Android phone, linked to from a web-page.

What's the simplest way to achieve this? I hope this will be very simple but unfortunately I don't have a phone on which to test.

Answer (score 0):

Your RTSP stream needs follow 3GPP PSS streaming spec to work with the android Videoplayer.

There is some more information here:

- [Server to stream RTSP to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613737/server-to-stream-rtsp-to-android)